# Filling combobox from database by using hibernate in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, swing, database, jcombobox

Heyy;

I am developing a small swing based application with hibernate in java. And I want fill combobox from database coloumn. How I can do that?

And I don't know in where(under `initComponents`, `buttonActionPerformd`)  I need to do.

For saving I'am using jbutton and it's code is here :

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

 int idd=Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());

 String name=jTextField2.getText();

 String description=jTextField3.getText();

 Session session = null;

 SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure()
    .buildSessionFactory();

 session = sessionFactory.openSession();

 Transaction transaction = session.getTransaction();

   try {


       ContactGroup con = new ContactGroup();

       con.setId(idd);

       con.setGroupName(name);
       con.setGroupDescription(description);



       transaction.begin(); 
       session.save(con); 
       transaction.commit(); 


      } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }

      finally{
       session.close(); 
      }    
}
```

Comment: You should not be performing database access in the Swing event dispatch thread - it blocks the UI until the database communication has completed. Have a look at SwingWorker and this tutorial: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Answer (score 5):

I don't use Hibernate, but given a JPA entity named `Customer` and a JPA controller named `CustomerJpaController`, you can do something like this.

Update: Code updated to reflect a switch to EclipseLink (JPA 2.1) as the persistence library.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
* @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2531942/230513
*/
public class CustomerTest implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new CustomerTest());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        CustomerJpaController con = new CustomerJpaController(
            Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("CustomerPU"));
        List<Customer> list = con.findCustomerEntities();
        JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(list.toArray());
        combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JComboBox cb = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
                Customer c = (Customer) cb.getSelectedItem();
                System.out.println(c.getId() + " " + c.getName());
            }
        });
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(combo);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Objects added to a [`JComboBox`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) get their display name from the object's `toString()` method, so `Customer` was modified to return `getName()` for display purposes:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getName();
}
```

You can learn more about [`JComboBox`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) in the article [*How to Use Combo Boxes*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).