# Is there an easy way to bind a Swing interface with a data source

Tags: java, swing, data-binding

I am programming the admin part of a Swing application using WindowBuider, it would basically be tables filled with items which I need to do a CRUD operations on them. the Data comes from MySQL database.
I can do it by hand but, it will take too long

Is there an easy way to do that ? using something like in Access forms...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard Swing components a too low level and do not provide anything like you need. If commercial solution is suitable from you, have a look at [JIDE](http://www.jidesoft.com/) components.

Answer (score 1):

The article [*Binding Beans and Data in a Desktop Application*](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-binding.html) shows how to bind persistent data to Swing components. NetBeans can generate entity classes from a database and create the corresponding Persistence Unit using any of several providers. This very simple [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531193/filling-combobox-from-database-by-using-hibernate-in-java/2531942#2531942) began with a `Customer` entity derived from an [H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) and accessed via a [Top-Link Essentials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TopLink) provider.

Answer (score 0):

[The NetBeans Platform](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/) contains all kinds of tables and data binding. Because it's built with Swing, you can use the components in regular swing apps.