# Java Swing 2 way binding

Tags: java, swing

Is there support for Java Swing to use 2 way binding like WPF?

If not, what might be the best way to achieve it?

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052174/is-there-an-easy-way-to-bind-a-swing-interface-with-a-data-source/7052833#7052833).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/libraries.html

2) http://java.net/projects/beansbinding/

Comment: http://kenai.com/projects/betterbeansbinding/pages/Home < betterbeansbinding might be better than beansbinding these days.

Comment: beansbinding is dead - successor (not much movement, though, though it's nearly as dead) is BetterBeansbinding at kenai - dont have the link handy, sorry

Comment: bbb seems to be here now too - http://code.google.com/p/betterbeansbinding/ - hasn't been updated in a while tho.