# Populate JCombobox with SimpleTable data

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, components

I have a table set up like so:

Table Roles:

```
super("ROLES", // Name
            true,   // Can insert
            true,   // Can modify
            true,   // Can delete
            true,   // Supports events
            "system_table_data/roles.dat",   // don't Journal to disk
            1, // Read Access Level
            1, // Write Access Level (controlled via GUI)
            // Field Info
            new Object[][] {// Key    Name               Type         Read  Write  Insert  Modify
                           {PK_FIELD, "ROLE_ID",         "ROLE_ID",   YES,  YES,    NO,     NO},  // 0 BYTE
                           {NM_FIELD, "ROLE_NAME",       "STRING_80", YES,  YES,    YES,    YES}, // 1 
                           {NM_FIELD, "SHIFT_PATTERN_ID","SHIFT_PAT", YES,  YES,    YES,    YES}, // 2 BYTE
                           {NM_FIELD, "START_DATE",      "CS_TIME",   YES,  YES,    YES,    YES}, // 3
                           }
           );
```

and

Table Shift Pattern:

```
super("PATTERNS", // Name
            true,   // Can insert
            true,   // Can modify
            true,   // Can delete
            true,   // Supports events
            "system_table_data/patterns.dat",   // don't Journal to diskmember_hna
            1, // Read Access Level
            1, // Write Access Level (controlled via GUI)
            // Field Info
            new Object[][] {// Key    Name               Type         Read  Write  Insert  Modify
                           {PK_FIELD, "NAME_ID",    "PATNAME_ID",     YES,  YES,    NO,     NO},  // 0
                           {NM_FIELD, "NAME",       "STRING_80",      YES,  YES,    NO,    YES},  // 1
                           }
           );
```

I am using JTables and pop out dialog boxes with fields to populate the tables and storing the information in tables such as these two.

It is all in a tabbed pane: a tab for Roles and a tab for the Shift pattern.

In the Roles pane, the dialog box has a combobox that should be populated by the name of the Shift Patterns, I want to know of a way to do this?

Comment: sorry out of ideas from your question, a.m. description, DYM each from JComboBoxes has different model, data, items and structure e.i. ????

Comment: There's an example using JPA [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2531942/230513).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having straight `Object[]` why not have a custom class like `Pattern[]` with a `toString()` method and then just create a `JComboBox(Object[])` with the `Pattern[]`?
( [API Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#JComboBox%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) )
It would then use the `toString()` method to display the pattern text as the selection and you can get the selected `Pattern` and do whatever you need with it.