# JFreeChart & Lazy loading

Tags: hibernate, charts, window, jfreechart

I'm trying to make new functionality to my app. And I faced the fact, that my app should work with big data (over 1000+ entries).Also, I'd like to mention, that data (dataset - call it how you want) is taken from DB by Hibernate. I wish i could post some code how exactly i retrieve data and add it to dataset, but it's strictly prohibited.

Any ideas how to make it

Note: Window with chart looks like this: 
https://classic.moqups.com/AU/SmmGSpPE/p:a16b2c2a4
when window opens - all dataset is loaded, however only one piece of window show chart. to see more, user have to click on

"<<<" or ">>>"

buttons. That will result in 'reloading data from DB' (which actually is not). it only displays what comes after the first "step" and e.t.c

I tried to explain clearer as i could.

Thanks for tips and suggestions

Comment: Oh, consider as INPUT parameter Array of x and y with randomly generated values.

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6849654/230513)?

Comment: Yep, thats exactly what i need. But one problem still unresolved - how to correctly bind to my Service...but anyways. Thanks!

Comment: I've cited some relevant examples below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to correctly bind to my `Service`?

I'm not familiar with Hibernate, but you can query a JPA entity, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2531942/230513), but do so in the `doInBackground()` implementation of a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513). Update the chart's dataset in your implementation of `process()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13205322/230513). The listening chart will update itself in response. You can page through the dataset using an approach such the one shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849654/230513).

Comment: I don't understand. What precludes this approach?